# Regex to validate phone numbers, making sure there are no letters in them

Tags: regex

We have a live project and I need to filter out letters from any phone numbers, using a regex.

Being live, I cannot fiddle very much with it, so I am thinking of this regex:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

Do you think it will do the trick? eliminate phone numbers which contains letters?

Being a multicultural site, do you know of any country who uses letters in their phone numbers?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to filter our letters from any phone numbers or filter out phone numbers that contain letters?  Your example suggests the latter but your question the former.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: It's common in the US for businesses to get vanity phone numbers that spell something related to their name, like 1-800-MATTRES or 1-800-FLOWERS. But ordinary people don't get numbers like this, and they don't need to be entered into contact fields. And until the 70's, phone exchanges had names that were used for the first two digits. (When I was a kid, our phone number was WElls 5-9788.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your current regex, I am assuming that you need a regex that will only match valid inputs.

Your current regex will work fine to prevent letters, but I think it would make more sense to figure out the minimum set of characters you consider valid and create a regex for that.

For example if you only want to allow digits you could use `^\d*$` or `^[0-9]*$`.

To also allow spaces, hyphens, and parentheses so a number like `(123) 456-7890` would be valid:

```
^[\d \-()]*$
```